# Mongoose: Why can I find a document when a parameter is a string but not a number in a query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an object in my mongo database that looks like this:

```
{
   name: 'test',
   sku: 11223344
}
```

I am trying to find the item by `sku` like such:

```
Products.findOne({sku: 11223344}, function (err, product) {
  if (product) {
   // Do something
  }
  return
});
```

However this **never** returns the item.  I can inspect my database with Robomongo and I can see that I am typing the number **exactly** right and that `type` of `sku` in mongo is `double`.

Strangely, when I convert the `sku` to a `string`, and pass in a `string`, I can find the item.

Is there some sort of limit to precision, or some reason that I would be able to find an item when the query property is specified as a string but not a number?

Here is my Schema for the item:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');                                                                                                                                                                                 

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;                                                                                                                                                                                       

var productSchema = new Schema({                                                                                                                                                                                    
  // T-Shirt, jeans, etc                                                                                                                                                                                            
  kind: {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  title: {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  edition: {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  urlEdition: {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  flavor: {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  urlFlavor: {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  itemDetails: {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    type: Array                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  sizes: {                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    type: {}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  sizeGuide: {                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  description: {                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  shortDescription: {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  aboutSpecific: {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  careInstructions: {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  images: {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    type: {}                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  sku: {                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    type: String                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the schema for `Products`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK updated! I see something! I did specify the `sku` as a string when I made the Schema.  I guess that matters even though I ultimately store it in Mongo as a number and query it as a number?

Comment: Yep, your schema needs to match the documents in the collection. So in this case `sku` should be `sku: { type: Number }`.

Comment: I wish I could accept comments. I don't know why I never checked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field definitions of your schema need to match the documents in the collection for queries to work properly as Mongoose performs value casting based on the schema.

So in this case `sku` needs to be defined as a number instead:

```
sku: {
    type: Number
}
```